# add flag to intent in Titanium

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, appcelerator

I develop an application on titanium/appcelerator for android and just figured out  that if application is "force stopped" push notifications will not come to the device by default - http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html however there is a flag in documentation that can help me:

> FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Include intent filters of stopped applications in the list of potential targets to resolve against.

This flag is for intent but i cannot figure out how to set up it on titanium platform correctly.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `addFlags(flags)` method which is provided by Titanium for Android intents (alternatively use `setFlag(flag)`). It adds the flags to the flags the intent already has.

Short example:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
    url: 'activity1.js'
});
intent.addFlags(FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES); //WARNING: READ ON BELOW
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Unfortunately Titanium [does not support](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Intent-method-addFlags) the flag you need. Now you have three options:

1. Inform the Titanium devs that the flag is missing and ask them to include it in a future release. But this could take a long time
2. Try to avoid it completely
3. Try to use the constant value the flag has: 0x00000020 . I do not know whether Titanium can work this out by the flag constant but you should give it a try.